# Jekyll: Is there a way to change the color of the markdown processing in GitHub pages?

Tags: html, css, github, jekyll, github-pages

I am wondering how I could change the color scheme for the markdown processing in GitHub pages, but I somehow could not find the exact places to do so.

I have tried to change the syntax highlighting css and the JS library to no avail. I have also tried to search for the coloring scheme for the webpage, but none of the color matches what is found below. I suspect it has to do either Markdownify or Kramdown in Github pages - but are they doing the same function? My impression is that markdownify changes markdown to html, while kramdown handles the coloring scheme. Is this correct?

I see that the coloring scheme for keywords like `keywords` is quite different from what I found on other websites but I have no clue how to change this. I hope it could be changed to something that resembles the GitHub markdown rendering (which looks very similar to the one in Stack Overflow).

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you can. By default GitHub Pages use the [syntax highlighter](https://help.github.com/articles/using-syntax-highlighting-on-github-pages/) Rouge, which is compatible with Pygments, which in turn has a bunch of [themes](https://github.com/richleland/pygments-css). Just include one of those theme CSS files on every page of your site.